# How to I recurse through the nested class expressions using the OWLAPI?

Tags: owl-api

Given a class expression C, I would like to recursively iterate through its nested class expressions, like

- A and R some P some B

  - A
  - R some P some B

    - P some B

      - B

It is possible to build an index bottom up with OWLObject.getNestedClassExpressions(), but that seems a bit of an overkill. Is there a better way (OWLAPI 4)?

Answer (score 0):

The `ExistentialCollector` is an example that could fit. It only recurses through intersections and you'd need to change to recurse through all expression types, but that's the basic principle - in OWLAPI 5 you could write one method to traverse them all, using `components()`, but in OWLAPI 4 you'll have to write the traverse method for each expression type.

```
public class ExistentialCollector extends OWLClassExpressionVisitorAdapter {

/* Collected axioms */
private final Map<OWLObjectPropertyExpression, Set<OWLClassExpression>> restrictions;

public ExistentialCollector(
        Map<OWLObjectPropertyExpression, Set<OWLClassExpression>> restrictions) {
    this.restrictions = restrictions;
}

@Override
public void visit(@Nonnull OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
    for (OWLClassExpression operand : ce.getOperands()) {
        operand.accept(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void visit(@Nonnull OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce) {
    Set<OWLClassExpression> fillers = restrictions.get(ce.getProperty());
    if (fillers == null) {
        fillers = new HashSet<>();
        restrictions.put(ce.getProperty(), fillers);
    }
    fillers.add(ce.getFiller());
}
}
```